# Getting "error fetch failed" in the terminal when starting new Astro project

Tags: npm, astrojs

I'm trying to learn how to build websites using **Astro static website generator** and thus was trying to start the blog project that's in its documentation for learning purposes. The thing is when I run `npm create astro@latest` to create my new astro project, I'm getting the following error message in the terminal:

```
▲  error fetch failed
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/<my.username>
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c create-astro
```

What should I do? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check your npm/yarn/pnpm registry config like:

`npm config get registry`

And validate your URL's. I have set the registry address by:

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com`

and it will be fine when I removed it